# oracle stored procedure inserting multiple record

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In the below procedure, I want to insert multiple id records for approval_log_id column which is a foreign key for approval_redirect_log table.

I am getting approval_log_id from another table approval_log.The select query for the first column returns multiple ids which should be inserted along with other data. Other columns data has to be repeated for all the ids.

What am I doing wrong here for the first column?

```
    PROCEDURE REDIRECT_APPROVAL_LOG_INSERT(
vAPPROVAL_LOG_ID approval_redirect_log.approval_log_id%type,
vREDIRECTED_FROM APPROVAL_REDIRECT_LOG.redirected_from%type,
vREDIRECTED_TO APPROVAL_REDIRECT_LOG.redirected_to%type,
vREDIRECTED_BY approval_redirect_log.redirected_by%type) AS

  BEGIN

   INSERT INTO APPROVAL_REDIRECT_LOG(
     APPROVAL_LOG_ID,
     REDIRECTED_FROM,
     REDIRECTED_TO,
     REDIRECTED_BY,
     REDIRECTED_ON) 
  VALUES
  (select approval_log_id 
   from approval_log 
   where accept_reject is null and approval_recid=vREDIRECTED_FROM
   ,
  vREDIRECTED_FROM,
  vREDIRECTED_TO,
  vREDIRECTED_BY,
  sysdate
  );

  END REDIRECT_APPROVAL_LOG_INSERT;
```

Comment: Your syntax is completely wrong: `values` shouldn't appear for insert/select, you select a single column but insert many, the end of the where clause is funky. I suggest you start by getting this to work outside a stored procedure first, then transform it into a store procedure.

Comment: Oh..ok..As I am an mssql developer and new to plsql, there are chances of syntax mistake. Thanks. Will try with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

```
INSERT INTO APPROVAL_REDIRECT_LOG(
     APPROVAL_LOG_ID,
     REDIRECTED_FROM,
     REDIRECTED_TO,
     REDIRECTED_BY,
     REDIRECTED_ON) 
select    approval_log_id, 
          vREDIRECTED_FROM,
          vREDIRECTED_TO,
          vREDIRECTED_BY,
          sysdate
from approval_log 
where  
     accept_reject is null 
     and approval_recid=vREDIRECTED_FROM;
```